# Running the Android Emulator does not give any results

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem, to be honest I do not understand what I'm doing wrong ..
Every time I try to run my layout in the Android Emulator, it shows me the main menu of the phone itself.

I tried to edit the code in AndroidManifest.xml but it didn't work, I changed devices, cold start, restarted the app and deleted the emulator, none of it worked.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TATTOFOUNDLER"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/LoginPage"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: check first which page open that page exported use true.other pages use false

Comment: check my code u have use

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TATTOFOUNDLER"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/LoginPage"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       </application>

     </manifest>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3WXxE0l (screenshot)

Either I misunderstood, or nothing has changed)

Comment: check ur side errors there

Comment: LoginActivity check u taking not Activity

Comment: It is in the AndroidManifest.xml file that it does not find errors, in the LoginActivity file the errors are related to the Google login binding, this is a slightly different situation.

Comment: delete LoginActivity page create again

Comment: sooo... nothing changed

Comment: send me screenshort

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IfvPAqj

Comment: take new LoginActivity

Comment: check different LoginActivity is white other classes green so u take wrong

Comment: At the moment I have it empty, do you mean that? Still not working(

Comment: check u take Activity or Interface

Comment: check Cleary ok

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, he takes the information from Activity, but initially I just wanted to check the design from the XML file.

Comment: Everything is correct in the code, and everything is fine in the xml file as well. I recreated Activity several times and left it empty and filled, revised the ХML Manifest, in the same way - everything seems to be fine, but something is not right.

Comment: U clear issue?? in XML side

Comment: Missing `contentDescription` attribute on image, That's all, but it's not that important as far as I know.